# Is there any other way to use bracket notation on Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have this template on Javascript:

```
var _template = Handlebars.compile('\
<button id="btn" onclick="btnColor('color','blue')"></button>\
 ');
```

As you can see I use this (') bracket notations here ('color','blue').
And because Handlebars starts like this ('), I can not use the function btnColor, it turns out wrong.

```
function btnColor(btn, color) {
var element = document.getElementById(btn);

if (element.className !== "toggle") {
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    element.className = "toggle";
} else {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#ddd";
    element.className = "";
}
```

}

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried slashes? <button id="colorView" onclick="btnColor(\''color\'',\''blue\'')"></button>\
 ');

Comment: This is part of the reason why inline event handlers are not good practice. Use an unobtrusive event handler and the problem goes away entirely, and the code quality improves.

Comment: Nice trick  @Arthur Borba, very nice, but the script  doesn't understand the color or blue (\''color\'',\''blue\'')... any other suggestion?

Comment: is this 'btnColor' function your function? what exactly do you mean by "...the script doesn't undestand the color or bue..."?

Comment: When I add slashes on Handlebars, although the error is corrected, it does not recognize the function btnColor eg toggle two colors, from blue to orange .

Comment: Hummm, how is this function defined?

Comment: @ Arthur Borba I update my status.. if you can help , I will be glad.. Thanks...

Comment: I don't understand this. Is there a <button> element with the id of "color"?

Comment: It's a button that toggle background color (it's more than that..). But the problem is that when I use slashes INSIDE the words ('color','blue')  --> (\'color\',\'blue\') , the function doesn't work.. So do you know another way to avoid Handlebars issue? Maybe something on the start and end on Template ('\ , ');

Comment: I think you are confused about your function parameters. You are trying to get an element from the document with an id equal to the value of the `btn` parameter, the first argument to the function, which is "color" when the function is invoked with `btnColor('color','blue')`. Your problem has nothing to do with Handlebars. The suggestion to use the back-slashes is a good one. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/at32nv1y/

Comment: Hi 76484That's a great example on jsfiddle!!! You can write it as an answer if you want. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the quotes in the template string.

```
var _template = Handlebars.compile('\
   <button id="colorView" onclick="btnColor(\'color\',\'blue\')"></button>\
 ');
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes that's what @Arthur Borba said. But If I do this then function btnColor doesn work because it doesnt recognise i.e  the color blue